# SQL SERVER - Create Table by matching rows and columns and put Y or N

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows, pivot-table

I currently have a table with all the data, using this data i want to create another table which could be used for auditing purpose (similar layout like pivot table)

Example Below:

Raw Data

```
Name         Places Visited
----------------------------
Will         London

John         Toronto

Dave         New York

Will         London
```

What I want (similar to Pivot Table but I can use letters):

```
Name/Places Visted    London      Toronto      New York

Will                    Y           N             Y

John                    N           Y             N

Dave                    N           N             Y
```

Any help to produce this will be much appreciated!

I hope i've explained myself well but let me know if you would like to clarify anything.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Why the close vote? The question seems very clear to me. He wants an SQL query that reads from a table containing the "raw data" and gives his desired output.

Comment: @Mo.: Maybe take a look at PIVOT (assumes SQL Server 2005 or newer): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I've tried it in Excel but couldnt think of a way to do in SQL, I'm quite a beginner in SQL. Using the PIVOT, will it allow me to use my own letters e.g. Y OR N? thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for SQL Server 2005/2008:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE 
(
     Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,Place NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @Temp 
SELECT 'Will','London'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John','Toronto'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dave','New York'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Will','London';

SELECT  
    pvt.Name [Name/Places Visted]
    ,CASE WHEN [London] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [London]
    ,CASE WHEN [Toronto] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [Toronto]
    ,CASE WHEN [New York] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END [New York]
FROM    @Temp src
PIVOT( MAX(src.Place) FOR src.Place IN([London], [Toronto], [New York]) ) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.Name DESC;
```

Results:

```
Name/Places Visted  London Toronto New York
------------------- ------ ------- --------
Will                Y      N       N
John                N      Y       N
Dave                N      N       Y
```

Note: Columns resulting from `PIVOT` operation are static. This means that if you add records with `Place='PARIS'` you should modify the query like this: `PIVOT( MAX(src.Place) FOR src.Place IN([London], [Toronto], [New York], [Paris])`. So, *you could use `PIVOT` operator if you have a limited number of cities*.

Comment: Thank you very much! will I have to input the names and location individually - i have table with around 200 records? thank you

Comment: Doesn't matter how many records you have. What matters is the number of DISTINCT places/cities.

Comment: With unknown number of cities you could use dynamic SQL sentences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271609/inserting-and-transforming-data-from-sql-table/7276229#7276229) I have presented a solution for a variable number of columns (columns resulted from `PIVOT` operation).

Comment: You should use `COUNT` aggregate function: `SELECT pvt.* FROM @Temp src 
PIVOT( COUNT(src.Place) FOR src.Place IN([London], [Toronto], [New York]) ) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.Name DESC`